# Functions returning functions approach in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, closures

I have almost a half year since I continuously learn JavaScript and started to use more seriously. JS has the C like syntax and other parts like closures, dynamic typing, optional paramates, etc.

The language feature that still I don't see his power is: **functions that return functions**:

```
function func(){
   return function(){
       ....
      return result;
   };
};


func()();
```

It's very cool and I know that is normal feature of functional languages but I never used in real world and I wonder i any of you had to work more with this kind of approach and in which situations that would show his real power.

I have also make a small example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bogdan_vq/2YR3k/1/).

Comment: `// HANDLE: $(DOMElement)
} else if ( selector.nodeType ) {
  this.context = this[0] = selector;
  this.length = 1;
  return this;

// HANDLE: $(function)
// Shortcut for document ready
} else if ( jQuery.isFunction( selector ) ) {
     return rootjQuery.ready( selector );
}`


when returning this, can that be considered returning a function or passing the context of that function further ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another use case: the function which performs different actions for the first and subsequent runs:

```
function test() {
    alert("the first call");
    test = function() {
        alert("new function");
    }
}
```

Comment: i think that could be dangerous for the integrity of the code

Comment: @BogdanVolosincu Well it can be very useful. For example you want to make some initialization, set up, but you want this to be done on the first function call only.

Comment: This answer is possibly interesting but does not address the question, which is about functions that return functions.

Answer (score 1):

It's useful when binding events. example:

```
var element1 = document.getElementById('element1');
var element2 = document.getElementById('element2')

element1.addEventListener('click', someEventHandler('action1'));
element2.addEventListener('click', someEventHandler('action2'));

function someEventHandler(act){
    return function(e){
       switch (act){
           case 'action1':
               // do something;
           break;
           case 'action2':
               // do other thing
           break;
       }
    }
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wsPr/)